# What makes a program Linux compatible/incompatible?

Tags: linux, java, compatibility

I understand that Linux does not support .exe's, but is adding Linux support as simple as providing a .jar version? This summer I'm going to try to really start programming and contributing to... well anything I can. I think Linux is the future. So what makes or breaks compatibility? What do I need to change about my Java/Python programs to make them compatible?

Comment: Java/Python code that contains no platform-specific part is compatible on all language supported platform. Remember: filename extensions has nothing to do with platform compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using languages, which leverage bytecode for platform independece, you have nothing special to do, to run e.g. `Java` or `Python`. As long as the runtimes are supported by linux - which is the case for the mentioned languages - you have nothing to do.

The only thing which differs under linux is the way how you actually *run* (e.g. *start*) the software. It is common to write start(shell-)scripts.